# Javascript - getting return value for setTimeout in recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, return, settimeout

I have a recursive function which contains some drawing code inside.  I was advised to use setTimeout as my drawing was not being displayed until the end of exection.  First I put just the drawing code inside setTimeout but this did not help, however when I put the main recursive loop inside setTimeout the drawing worked perfectly, as shown below.

However I need to use the return value of setTimeout (i.e. `state` as shown below).  How can I get this return value when using setTimeout, or solve this problem in another way.

```
var doLearning = function(time, observedData, state, domain, sampleAction, selectModel, numSamples, depth, discount, stateQueries) {
    if(stateQueries[0](time, state) === true) {
        console.log("New Round");
        var currentModel = selectModel(observedData, 10, stateQueries);
        var bestAction = sparseSampleMcmc(depth, numSamples, discount, currentModel, state, sampleAction, stateQueries);
        var newStateReward = domain.executeAction(bestAction, stateQueries);
        observedData.push(bestAction, newStateReward[1], newStateReward[0]);
        console.log(time);
        setTimeout(doLearning, 100, time + 1, observedData, newStateReward[0], domain, sampleAction, selectModel, numSamples, depth, discount, stateQueries);
    } else {
        console.log("Game Over");
        return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* you need that value? It might help us provide an appropriate answer.

Comment: The recursion is the call to doLearning.  I need the value because doLearning is actually also called by selectModel. It returns a model which I use in the following steps, such as in selecting a bestAction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an object with all your vars, like:

```
var game = {
     time: ... ,
     observedData: ...., 
     state: .... etc
 }
```

In `doLearning` get and modify this object's properties when necessary:

```
  var doLearning = function(obj) {

       if(obj.state == ....)
           obj.currentModel = whatever...
           obj.bestAction = whatever...
           setTimeout(function() { doLearning(obj) }, 100)
       else
           game over
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives me the willies to say, but what if you had a global variable where the return value would go? Set it at the end of doLearning, Then when you detect that the timeout/drawing is done, check the global.

Comment: Doesn't have to be global – just outside the scope of `doLearning`.

Answer (score 0):

Without all the code I'm having a hard time understanding, but perhaps it would be better to use `setInterval` here is a simple example.

```
function draw(){
  var state=//whatever
  var num = setInerval(doLearning,100)  

  function doLearning(){
    //You have access and can modify state and do not need to return its value
    if(){}
    else{
      clearInterval(num);
      console.log('Game over');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling as follows, the current *execution context* (ie. the environment of the current instance of doLearning) forms a *closure* in which `time`, `observedData` etc. remain available to the anonymous function defined inside the `setTimeout()` statement.

Thus, the following should work:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    doLearning(time + 1, observedData, newStateReward[0], domain, sampleAction, selectModel, numSamples, depth, discount, stateQueries);
}, 100);
```